# how to retrieve array of values in the controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, visual-studio-2010

I am using asp.net MVC3.
In my view I have an array and I am passing this array to the controller like

```
return{model:JSON.stringify("array")};
```

In the controller I gave like

```
public ActionResult SearchDetails( string model)     //To load the SearchResults List view
{              
}
```

while i am executing,when i put the cursor it is displaying like
`"\"[{\\\"id\\\":1 "id\\\":2}]\""`. I want to retrieve these values in my controller but i dont want to use `for/foreach` loop.how can i do this

Comment: format your code... that is horrible

Answer (score 0):

Did you read this topic about array model and modelbinding?

[ASP.NET Wire Format for Model Binding to Arrays, Lists, Collections, Dictionaries](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETWireFormatForModelBindingToArraysListsCollectionsDictionaries.aspx)

Comment: hi, Thanks for the response.In that site you have given he has implemented using foreach loop but i dont want to use looping statements.